# What happened to Judith?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In the The Walking Dead episode "The Grove" (S04E14) the end showed ...

> Carol shooting the lizzy in the head because she was a mentally unstable and dangerous and Tyrese and Carol decided she couldn't be around other people. We see Tyrese and Carol walking away from the house, but without a baby in their arms. When they showed the graves of the two girls, they also showed a 3rd smaller grave with baby shoes hanging on the cross. What happened? Did they kill Judith too?

If so, why?

Comment: If you watch this episode again, you will notice the "baby shoes" are also shown earlier in the episode.

Comment: why did they hang the baby shoes on the 3rd grave?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Examiner.com](http://www.examiner.com/article/the-walking-dead-4x14-where-was-baby-judith-at-the-end-of-the-grove)

> Some fans noticed that Tyreese had some sort of carrier on his back.
>   Inside it resembled a baby, although the shot of it wasn't close up.
>   This caused some confusion with fans on whether baby Judith was dead
>   or alive.
>
> On "The Talking Dead," the subject of baby Judith was brought up and
>   it was confirmed that the infant is alive and well. She was in the
>   carrier that was on Tyreese's back.
>
> If she had died, it would make sense why they wouldn't show her at
>   all. The death of two children is hard enough for one episode,
>   although one of them was a danger to survivors everywhere. But seeing
>   the death of a baby would be too much for many viewers. Not only that,
>   but fans are looking forward to Rick and Carl finding out that Judy is
>   alive after all.

From a different [Examiner.com](http://www.examiner.com/article/the-walking-dead-news-talking-dead-confirms-if-judith-is-dead-or-alive) article referencing the Talking Dead chat show:

> On March 16, "The Talking Dead" confirmed the fate of the baby.
>
> They didn't show Judith at the end of the episode when Carol and
>   Tyreese were walking away, but if you paid attention you could tell
>   she was there. He was wearing a yellow pouch on his back. Paying
>   attention to it you could tell that it was Judith and could see her
>   head with a hood on it.
>
> On "The Talking Dead," it was confirmed that yes that was Judith on
>   his back.

Comment: I did see the pack on his back but since they have always carried her in their arms or over their shoulder and having showed the baby grave it didn't strike me as being a baby.

Answer (score 6):

From someone who watched the show:

The baby was in a "papoose" on Tyrese's back.  There was no need to kill the baby, she was alive and well when Tyrese and Carol returned to find Lizzy covered in Mika's blood, and they would have made sure Judith was well protected from Lizzy afterwards.

Comment: +1 - Indeed, the way she was ignored is proof enough. They would just have made it *very* clear if Judith had died somehow or was killed by Lizzie, and what else should have happened to her.